# SQL Server CE's DDL parser is very picky but secretive about what it is finding fault with

Tags: sql, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, windows-ce, ddl

I keep getting "there was an error parsing the query" no matter what I try with my DDL.

So I need an expert in the SQL-Server-CE flavor of SQL to tell me which of the following is the preferred method (or something else, quite likely). Note that I'm not worried about "SQL injection" with these string format elements:

1)

```
string ddl = string.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD salvationID nvarchar(19)", tablename);
ddl = string.Format("UPDATE {0} SET redemptionID = ''", tablename);
```

2)

```
string ddl = string.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD salvationID nvarchar(19) NOT NULL", tablename);
ddl = string.Format("UPDATE {0} SET redemptionID = ''", tablename);
//explicitly supplying the empty string
```

3)

```
string ddl = string.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD salvationID nvarchar(19) NOT NULL", tablename);
//assuming the empty string is supplied automatically
```

4)

```
string ddl = string.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD salvationID nvarchar(19) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT", tablename);
//assuming it automatically provides an empty string val
```

5)

```
string ddl = string.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD salvationID nvarchar(19) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT ''", tablename);
//specifying the default val explicitly - an empty string
```

6)

```
string ddl = string.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD salvationID nvarchar(19) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT {1}", tablename, string.empty);
//specifying the default val explicitly - an empty string via a string format element
```

7)

```
string ddl = string.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD salvationID nvarchar(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''", tablename);
//omitting the "WITH" keyword and specifying the default val explicitly - an empty string
```

8)

```
string ddl = string.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD salvationID nvarchar(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT {1}", tablename, string.empty);
//omitting the "WITH" keyword and specifying the default val explicitly - an empty string via a string format element
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE [{0}] ADD [salvationID] nvarchar(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123.aspx

Comment: Thanks; good thing I braced myself for something different than one of my options.

Comment: Does that go for all queries and ddl? IOW, should this:

string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}", tableName);

be:

string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [{0}]", tableName);

?

I'm still getting the dreaded, "there was an error parsing the query" and am having to look through every SQL statement to see what the problem might be.

Comment: Yes, if the table name has two or more Words, otherwise it is not required

Comment: It actually seemed to cause me problems doing that with the columns named "name"

Comment: name is probably a reserved Word, so enclosing the column name in brackets will solev that - I have updated my reply

Comment: No, it actually caused problems - I had to remove the brackets from the places where I had changed "name" to "[name]". Strange, I know, but this project's name (no pun intended) is Strange (so to speak).